What is this movie about a family who adopts a girl who ends up killing them all?
This movie begins with a couple in some kind of adoption house there they meet some kids but there they hear a piano (I think) and follow it where they meet another girl, they adopt her and the girl lives with them. 
Later we learn that the couple had a son and a daughter, the daughter is mute I think). I forgot what happens later but about half way though the movie the adopted girl then cuts down a tree where the boy had a tree house the boy survives and gets sent to the hospital the boy knows that it was the adopted girl but promises to not tell anyway. 
A bit later on the mute girl comes with her grandmother along with the adopted girl. The adopted girl kills the boy with his pillow the girl sees this, but, since she's mute and her grandmother doesn't know sign language she forgets about it (I think).
A bit further on the mom gets sent to the hospital because of something and while she's there the adopted girl starts flirting with the dad then the adopted girl kills the dad (I think). 
While at the hospital the mom who adopted the killer girl finds out that the girl was some kind of grown serial killer woman, she then goes home and tried to stop the serial killer woman, the serial killer is now trying to chase the mute girl but the mum comes and saves her then the mom and the mute girl get split up and now they're near a frozen pond/lake where the mute girl finds the gun and shoots it and kills the serial killer. 
Oh and the little mute girl goes flying after shooting the gun.

Welcome to the community. If you know, please also describe the year you viewed it, the language, country and year of production. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Please make an effort to use formatting and punctuation. This giant block of text is difficult to read.

This is the 2009 film Orphan. The little girl is actually an old woman with a rare condition that retards her aging.

Kate and John Coleman are experiencing strains in their marriage after their third child is stillborn. They decide to adopt a 9-year-old Russian girl named Esther (Isabelle Fuhrman) from a local orphanage. While Kate and John's 7-year-old deaf-mute daughter Max embraces Esther immediately, their 12-year-old son Daniel is less welcoming. At school, a bully named Brenda taunts Esther, and she is eventually hurt when Esther pushes her off a slide and causes her to break her ankle.

All the plot points you describe are there:

Esther overhears this and confronts Daniel at the tree house before setting it on fire and escaping. Daniel falls trying to escape and is knocked unconscious. Esther attempts to finish him off, but Max stops her. While Daniel is hospitalized, Esther slips into his room and smothers him, but he is revived.

The flirting:

That night, a provocatively-dressed Esther tries to seduce a drunk John.

The ending:

Leena finds Kate and Max near a frozen pond. She lunges at Kate, hurling them both into the ice. 


Another post, another down vote.......
